# Macro that gets a list of all the tabs in a selected excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro in which one selects an excel file, and then it creates a column with the location of the selected file and all the tab names in the excel, in which the Macro lies.

I tried doing the following, but after it opens the document and goes through the names of tabs, nothing happens.

Thanks for any help!

Sub NewFileTabs()

```
Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
Const dfcAddress As String = "B1"


Dim nr_tab As Long
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim dr_1 As Long
Dim dData_1 As Variant
Dim sht As Object
Dim NewTemplate As Variant
Dim sFilePath As String


Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dName)
Dim dFileName As String: dFileName = dwb.Name
Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(dfcAddress)

NewTemplate = Application.GetOpenFilename
If NewTemplate <> False Then
    
    Set nwb = Workbooks.Open(NewTemplate)
    Dim sFolderPath_new As String: sFolderPath_new = nwb.Path & "\"
    Dim sFileName_new As String: sFileName_new = Dir(sFolderPath_new & "*.xls*")
    sFilePath = sFolderPath_new & sFileName_new
    nr_tab = nwb.Sheets.Count + 1
    ReDim dData_1(1 To nr_tab, 1 To 1)
    dData_1(1, 1) = sFilePath
    dr_1 = 1
    For Each sht In nwb.Sheets
        x = x + 1
        dData_1(x, 1) = sht.Name
    Next sht
    nwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    dCell.Resize(nr_tab).Value = dData_l ' write to destination worksheet
    End If
IsSuccess = True
```

End Sub

Comment: dCell.Resize(nr_tab).Value = dData_l don't you wanted to write dData_1 instead ? And also and your for loop don't you want to use dr_1 instead of x ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
dCell.Resize(nr_tab).Value = dData_l ' write to destination worksheet
```

Try:

```
Range(dCell, dCell.Offset(UBound(dData_1, 1)-1)) = dData_1
```

Might not be aware of it, but your dData array is one entry bigger than it needs to be, so you can change:

```
nr_tab = nwb.Sheets.Count + 1
```

to just

```
nr_tab = nwb.Sheets.Count
```

Otherwise it'll just populate an additional row beneath with an empty cell - probably no harm in it here - but if your ever fitting data into an enclosed space...

Comment: Perfect! It works. The only thing outstanding is that I get the warning regarding enabling/disabling the macros when the file opens. Is there a way for the macro to automatically select enable?

Comment: The only reason this solved the OPs issue is you silently fixed the typo (`dData_l` to `dData_1`).  Changing from Resize to Range is just another way of doing the same thing.